# Return Observable and subscribe in angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular service and having issues in setting up some properties (likely my understanding issues).

```
    @Injectable()
    export class MyService{
    hoHa:MyObj = null;

    someFunction(): Observable<MyObj>{

     return httpClient.get<MyObj[]>('url')
                      .pipe(
                        map(response => response[]),
                        catchError(this.handleError('someFunction', {} as MyObj)                  
                     )

    }
}
```

How to set the 'hoHa' service property in someFunction GET response? 
   In angularJs, I use to set the 'hoHa' in $http get success response.

How can I just return if the 'hoHa' is already set when someone calls someFunction? 
   In angularJs, I use to return $q.when() if the property is already set

Comment: @connorsFan i  am trying to see how can i do this in angular. Is there a reason why the tag was removed?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read carefully the last two paragraphs of the question. My bad.

Comment: Start with an angular tutorial on https://angular.io to understand how components and services interact. It should then become self evident. If not please post the **angular** code you have up to that point along with where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: @Igor I am having issues in setting up some properties..updated the question which i think is more clear than the previous one. Any suggestions?

Comment: @fireholster - you can use `tap` and still return the observable to the caller so they can subscribe.

Comment: @Igor Thanks..It was right there :-|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) and still return the observable to the caller so it can be subscribed to.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService{
    hoHa:MyObj = null;

    someFunction(): Observable<MyObj>{
        return httpClient.get<MyObj>('url')
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('someFunction', {} as MyObj), tap(result => this.hoHa = result));

    }
}
```

Comment: For the $.when() one can either use of({} as MyObj) or empty()